# Post Request using json file

Tags: node.js, json

I have created a JSON file and I am trying to do a post request to add more data into my JSON file.
I want to do this by using a req.body. Below are my JSON file and node js code.

```
  "recipes": [
{
   "recipe_id": "001",
   "food_recipe": "Fried Rice",
   "cook_time": 20,
   "ingridients": "white rice, eggs, mixed vegatable,hotsauce, soya sauce",
   "cooking_instructions": "https://therecipecritic.com/easy-fried-rice/"

}
]
}
```

allrecipes.json file above

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const recipes = require('./allrecipes');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/recone',(req,res)  => {
     let addrecipe = {
       recipe_id: "2",
       food_recipe: "Chicken Paramsean",
       cook_time: 40,
       ingridients: "chiken,breading,flour,egg,red sauce,mozzarella",
       cooking_instructions: "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/223042/chicken-parmesan/"
     };

     recipes.push(addrecipe);

  fs.writeFile('allrecipes.json',JSON.stringify(recipes), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send('New recipe added');
  });

  });
```

Above is my app.js file.

For testing purposes, I hardcoded the values in the object, but when I ran it I am getting an error saying push is not a function. My end result is to use JSON body to post data into my json file.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring the whole allrecipes file in app.js file. You only need to require the recipes array from the allrecipes.json file. So while requiring, do the following

let recipes=require('./allrecipes').recipes

Comment: thanks is there a way where I do not have to hard code my values or use req.body.field

Comment: From the view of websites, server receive post requests from client. Client posts data and the above code will be receive it in req.body!  If you have not developed a client code yet, you can test your endpoints using POSTMAN.

Comment: Im saying in my code if I want to replace recipe_id to the value of req.body.recipe_id I can do that like this recipe_id: req.body.recipe_id

Comment: Yes you can directly assign it. You can do anything you want with req.body

Comment: when I do that tho I still get the error that the push method is not a function

Comment: Did you require it as I mentioned above. If so you will get acccess to the array object and the error should be gone

Comment: actually this is what happens

Comment: [

{"recipe_id":"1","food_recipe":"Fried Rice","cook_time":20,"ingridients":"white rice, eggs, mixed vegatable,hotsauce, soya sauce","cooking_instructions":"https://therecipecritic.com/easy-fried-rice/"},
{"recipe_id":"2","food_recipe":"Chicken Paramsean","cook_time":40,"ingridients":"chiken,breading,flour,egg,red sauce,mozzarella","cooking_instructions":"https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/223042/chicken-parmesan/"}]  after I make the post request the name of the array disappears and eveytime I have to make the post request I have to go back to my json and add the name of the array back in

Comment: Do you mean adding the data to your .json file? If so, you should write the new data into the file. What you are doing is requiring a data from the file and using it in your program.  If you want to change the contents of the .json file, you have to write to it. Learn more about fs module in Node to read and write to files